# Select and group KonvaJS objects not working

Tags: konvajs

I want to create a "select and group" functionality for my KonvaJS application.

For the select functionality, I'm using this example that works well:
[selecting by drawing a box around objects in konva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395110/selecting-by-drawing-a-box-around-objects-in-konva)

But the group function is not working as I expect. This is what's happening:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKTbX.gif)

First I create an empty group like this:

```
selectGroup = new Konva.Group({
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    draggable: true
});
```

When a shape is hit I add it like this:

```
selectGroup.add(shapeObject);
```

And when I finish the selection I call the Transform functionality like this:

```
var tr = new Konva.Transformer();
layer.add(tr);
tr.attachTo(selectGroup);
layer.draw();
```

I don't why when I add a shape it disappears. And when I finish and I call the transform functionality it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a small demo? Probably when you add shape into the group its absolute is getting out of visible view.

Comment: Sure @lavrton. Here's a demo: https://jsbin.com/pubovu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Did you add `selectGroup` to the layer? Looks like it is not on the layer, so you don't see the shapes.

Comment: Thanks lavrton. That was the problem. Now is working fine. I can't drag the group, but that's another story. I'll continue investigating. Thanks again for this amazing framework!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to lavrton I saw that the problem was that I didn't add the `selectGroup` to the layer.

Right now is working fine. Problem fixed.