# Selecting multiple objects using the hitbox when drawing a box in konvajs

Tags: konvajs, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I'm currently trying to select multiple objects (specifically lines) and adding them to a **Group/Transformer** by drawing a box. To do this, I followed this very helpful [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395110/selecting-by-drawing-a-box-around-objects-in-konva).

After implementing it, I wasn't really happy with the results because I needed to check the entire list of shapes every time I drew the box even if I didn't pass through a shape.

In an attempt to find a solution to this problem, I thought that there might be a way for a line to know it had collided with the box being drawn. However, I have not been lucky to find out something similar to what I'm trying to reproduce. Is there an example or a way for me to draw a box to select multiple objects when they collide with the box?

Comment: Did you check this demo https://konvajs.org/docs/select_and_transform/Basic_demo.html? It shows selecting by a box.

Comment: Hi @lavrton, in that example they also had to get all the shapes in the stage when he calls **var shapes = stage.find('.rect').toArray()**. Is checking every shape in the stage the only way to check for intersections/collisions with the select box?

Comment: You may just try to do it once on mousedown. But I don't see any issues on doing that every mousemove. Do you have perf issues?

Comment: Not at the moment because I just have a few amounts of shapes. However, if I created a bunch more I wanted to know the best practice to tackle this problem. If I were to have a lot of shapes, wouldn't checking my entire list of shapes per mousemove greatly affect my performance?

Comment: If you are considering a custom method to find intersections keep in mind that you could have non-rectangular shapes, and even your rectangular shapes could be rotated.  Hit testing with those challenges can be an 'interesting' and high time-cost job. I believe Konvajs has some optimisation strategies that cover those points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking every shape in the stage is the only way to check intersections.

If you need some optimizations you can try [debouncing or throttle strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function).

E.g. check interactions every 100ms instead of every `mousemove` or `touchmove` events.